# YA/Children’s 2000s sci fi novel featuring a female spy/assassin in a world with flying cars and aerial highways

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, dystopia

I’m looking for a book I read about 12 years ago, I’m guessing it was written in the early 2000s but not positive.

I don’t remember much but it took place on a futuristic planet that had some sort of flying cars, and the “highways” were in the sky. The main character was a female protagonist who was a spy or assassin, I think she was being forced or blackmailed to work for the evil government or something like that.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You've tagged this question with "dystopia;" what made the setting dystopic?